# How to properly do a LOOP in mysql

Tags: mysql, for-loop

Ok this might be ridiculous but I've been scratching my head for quite a few minutes now. What is wrong with this syntax?

```
SET @maxIterations = 10;
SET @i = 0;

myloop: LOOP
    SET @i = @i + 1;

    UPDATE `mytable`
    SET `field` = 'value';

    if @i < @maxIterations THEN ITERATE myloop; END IF;

    LEAVE myloop;
END LOOP myloop;
```

I am getting error `near 'myloop: LOOP SET i = i + 1' at line 1`

Comment: Where are you executing this?  Flow control structures like `IF/ELSE` and `LOOP` are only valid inside a stored procedure or function, _not_ in any regular query.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/flow-control-statements.html _MySQL supports the IF, CASE, ITERATE, LEAVE LOOP, WHILE, and REPEAT constructs for flow control within stored programs._

Comment: Ahhh. Well. MySQL's error reporting not useful again as well as their documentation. I was curious why all the examples make use of procedures. Thanks. Please, add it as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is generally correct, except that MySQL does not permit flow control structures like `IF/ELSE, WHILE, LOOP` in anything other than a stored procedure or function ("stored programs").  This limitation [is documented here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/flow-control-statements.html):

> MySQL supports the IF, CASE, ITERATE, LEAVE LOOP, WHILE, and REPEAT constructs for flow control within stored programs. It also supports RETURN within stored functions.

You will be able to correctly create this as a stored procedure, as in:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc()
BEGIN
  SET @maxIterations = 10;
  SET @i = 0;

  myloop: LOOP
      SET @i = @i + 1;

      UPDATE `mytable`
      SET `field` = 'value';

      if @i < @maxIterations THEN ITERATE myloop; END IF;

      LEAVE myloop;
  END LOOP myloop;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Shame on mysql's documentation. I've searched for "mysql for loop" and got this poor article 'http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/loop.html'. As much as I don't get this mysql's design pattern I have nothing to do than to accept it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @JosefSábl Yes, unfortunately the docs expect you to traverse outward to the chapter intro, or start at the intro and traverse inward to get the full picture.